# Did listeners on panel in Ext JS 5 depends on the panel content?

Tags: iframe, listener, extjs5, pinch

I wan't to detect 'pinch' event on a Extjs 5 Panel, if I load the panel content using `loader` property it's working, but if I put an item (Iframe) in the panel, it doesn't work

Panel with an item (IFrame):

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        layout: 'fit',
        autoScroll: true,
        items: [
            Ext.create('Ext.ux.IFrame', {
                autoScroll: true,
                src: 'resources/docs/doc1.html',
                cls: 'iframeStyle'
            })
        ],
        listeners: {
            pinch: function (event) {
                alert('pinch event');
            },
            element: 'body'
        }
    })
```

Panel that the content was loaded using `loader` property

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        layout: 'fit',
        loader: {
            url: 'resources/docs/doc1.html',
            autoLoad: true
        },
        listeners: {
            pinch: function (event) {
                alert('pinch event');
            },
            element: 'body'
        }

    })
```

Can you explain me the difference, and why with an IFrame it doesn't work??
Thank you

Comment: Didn't you already ask a similar question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522395/pinch-event-on-iframe-extjs-5

Comment: Yes, but there are different problems

Comment: Why you deleted your answer? I'am trying it

Comment: Iframe is actually separate browser page inside other page. Because it is separate page it handles its own events. There are some methods to allow communication between frames, but it isn't straigtforward. You definitely don't get it out of box.